# Prime turns into Perfect Cube, if you reverse its digits and subtract....What is the number

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, no-computers

Given:

1) I have more than one digit.

2)  Reversed number is subtracted to give at least 2 digit number which should be a cube.

2) you don’t even need a calculator to figure me out.

Who am I?

Comment: 'Reverse digits and subtract' is a little vague.  There are already 2 valid interpretations of it below.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Simple, take 11, $11 -11 = 0 = 0 ^3$

Comment: From the prime number subtract the reverse number, result should result in cube of at least 2 digits.

Comment: **spoiler** FWIW [A080178](https://oeis.org/A080178) has such numbers (palindromic primes giving the trivial cube of zero)

Comment: Thx for info..I am familiar with lot of other prime related series but not this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> $41$. It is prime and
>
>  $41 - 14 = 27 = 3^3$

Reasoning

> Assuming the number has 2 digits, it can be written as
>
>  $10a+b$
>
>  Then
>
>  $(10a + b) - (10b + a) = 9(a-b)$
>
>   should be a non-zero cube. The only way to make it a non-zero cube with single digits $a$ and $b$, is to have
>
>  $a = b + 3$
>
>  The only 2 digit prime number that fits is $41$.
>
>  As far as uniqueness of this solution goes, it is easy to show that no 3 digit number fits. I guess this is as far as you can go without a calculator :-)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is

> 47

Same argument as [ppgdev](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57184/ppgdev)'s [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83996/39764), but

> $47 - 74 = -27 = (-3)^3$

Comment: Nice twist! (+1)!

Comment: True..as I did not specify it to be positive number.